Is it possible to reduce the size of the weird shadow my Google Material3 Text-Button makes?
I have recently started using m3.material.io's Web Library for my Login page and have noticed some issues. Since I have not been able to find proper documentation for this stuff, I must ask, can I somehow reduce a Text-Button shadow's size? Well, I have tried using the CSS properties like box-shadow, box-size and others, but since this is from a library that cannot really work.  In this short video (Here, the shadow can be seen behind the "Forgot ID?" button. Here is my code in Replit.
If anyone manages to find a solution, could you link the documentation where I can find these guides for future use?

Not sure if I understand your issue correctly. Are you referring to the shadow that appears behind the text when you hover the button?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
